# Can we have a "Private API tester" badge or repurpose an existing one?

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, api

For those who put a lot of hard work into testing/developing-against the API, I thought it would be nice to reward them with a badge.

The more I thought about it, I began to think:

> Why don't we repurpose an existing badge?

Since there is already a badge for participating in the private beta of SO, why don't we change it to say

> This badge is awarded to those who participated in testing something on StackOverflow.

Of course, the wording needs to be changed, but you get the idea.

Comment: I thought I'd seen this before, but can't find it now. (Maybe it was an answer or comment on something else?)

Comment: Maybe this would be a good use for the mythic "Hacker" badge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Opening up the Beta badge to be attainable in the future would make it less exclusive (full disclosure: I don't have it), which some users may object to.

However, I think the following should outweigh any user objections:

- Promoting participation in any current or future beta testing
- Keeping the badge system simpler (use the same badge vs. adding a new badge for every beta)

Overall, I support this idea, as I think the benefits are better than the drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

All the badges are rewarded automatically, but this one really needs to be handawarded. Or do you see any automatable ways? I don't expect Jeff to add a handawarded badge to the set.

Nevertheless, the idea is nice.